# Configure Prettier to use up the max allowed number of columns if code content will fit

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure Prettier in such a way to use up as much column space allowed, while still respecting the rest of the prettier/lint rules configured? So, if Prettier's `printWidth` is set to `80` for example, and your code runs over that amount, prettier will wrap the line, but if you manually wrap your lines even though they could fit within a single line, Prettier won't do the reverse and put it all on one line.

So for example:

```
const someObject = {
  someProperty: 'some value',
};
```

could easily fit into a single line: `const someObject = {someProperty: 'some value'};` but prettier won't remove the new lines and put everything on one line.

Comment: No, its not possible. Prettier implements a formatting configuration that is considered to be **"Biased"**, meaning it comes per-configured, there are some major benefits that come from being biased, and some disadvantages. If you want to customize the formatting, then you should check out ESLint. ESLint implements  an "auto-fix" feature that formats your code, and Lints it as well. It doesn't format everything that prettier does, but it is highly configurable. Most people default to ESLint now'a days.